# In oracle, how to 'group by' properties that are in comma separated values?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, count, group-by

Say, I have a table like

```
Name   Pets
-------------------------
Anna   Cats,Dogs,Hamsters
John   Cats
Jake   Dogs,Cats
Jill   Parrots
```

And I want to count, how many people have different types of pets. The output would be something like

```
Pets     Owners
---------------
Cats     3
Dogs     2
Hamsters 1
Parrots  1
```

**Limitations:**

- Reworking of DB scheme is impractical. If I could do it, I wouldn't be here.
- All logic must be done in one SQL query.
- I can't take result table and deduce owner count later in code.
- Using built-in Oracle functions is OK, but writing custom functions is discouraged.
- Oracle version – 11 and up.

Comment: This table is not meeting the least requirements of a database table! the first normalized form should be met at least.

Comment: Is the list of possible pets limited? Stored somewhere in a separate table?

Comment: yasserkabbout: originally the "Pets" field was meant as a logging field, that should only show up in reports.
StanislavL: Limited? Not in a mathematical sense. In separate table? Yes, BUT user can delete records from that table, but this deletion does not (and must not) affect the table the table presented here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a terrible design - as you mentioned - so I don't envy you having to work with it!

It's possible to do what you're after, although I wouldn't like to say that it would be performant for larger datasets!

Assuming the `name` column is the primary key (or at least unique):

```
with t1 as (select 'Anna' name, 'Cats,Dogs,Hamsters' pets from dual union all
            select 'John' name, 'Cats' pets from dual union all
            select 'Jake' name, 'Dogs,Cats' pets from dual union all
            select 'Jill' name, 'Parrots' pets from dual)
select pet pets,
       count(*) owners 
from   (select name,
               regexp_substr(pets, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) pet
        from   t1
        connect by prior name = name
                   and prior sys_guid() is not null
                   and level <= regexp_count(pets, ',') + 1)
group by pet
order by owners desc, pet;


PETS           OWNERS
---------- ----------
Cats                3
Dogs                2
Hamsters            1
Parrots             1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad design to store **comma-separated** values in a **single column**. You should consider **normalizing the data**. Having such a design will always push you to have an overhead of manipulating delimited-strings.

Anyway, as a workaround, you could use **REGEXP_SUBSTR** and **CONNECT BY** to split the comma-delimited string into multiple rows and then count the pets.

There are other ways of doing it too, like **XMLTABLE**, **MODEL** clause. Have a look at **[split the comma-delimited string into multiple rows](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-in-oracle/)**.

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 'Anna' NAME, 'Cats,Dogs,Hamsters' pets FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'John' NAME, 'Cats' pets FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'Jake' NAME, 'Dogs,Cats' pets FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'Jill' NAME, 'Parrots' pets FROM dual
  6  )
  7  -- end of sample_data mimicking a real table
  8  SELECT pets,
  9    COUNT(*) cnt
 10  FROM
 11    (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(t.pets, '[^,]+', 1, lines.COLUMN_VALUE)) pets
 12    FROM sample_data t,
 13      TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
 14      (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(t.pets, ',')+1
 15      ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
 16    ORDER BY NAME,
 17      lines.COLUMN_VALUE
 18    )
 19  GROUP BY pets
 20  ORDER BY cnt DESC;

PETS                      CNT
------------------ ----------
Cats                        3
Dogs                        2
Hamsters                    1
Parrots                     1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

My try, only with substr and instr :)

```
with a as (
select 'Anna' as name,   'Cats,Dogs,Hamsters' as pets from dual union all
select 'John',   'Cats' from dual union all
select 'Jake',   'Dogs,Cats' from dual union all
select 'Jill',   'Parrots' from dual
),
b as(
select name, pets, substr(pets, starting_pos, ending_pos - starting_pos) pet
from (
      select name, pets, 
             decode(lvl, 1, 0, instr(a.pets,',',1,lvl-1))+1 starting_pos, 
             instr(a.pets,',',1,lvl) ending_pos
      from (select name, pets||',' pets from a
            )a 
             join (select level lvl from dual connect by level < 10)
          on instr(a.pets,',', 1, lvl) > 0
      )
)
--select * from b
select pet, count(*) from b group by pet;
```

Comment: I prefer this answer as it does not use regex

Answer (score 0):

```
select x pets ,count(x)   Owners from (     
select  extractvalue(value(x), '/b') x
  from  (select  yourcolumn as str from yourtable) t,
        table(
              xmlsequence(
                          xmltype('<a><b>' || replace(str, ',', '</b><b>') || '</b></a>' ).extract('/*/*')
                         )
             ) x)
             group by x;
```

/*replace yourcolumn with your column name (pets) and yourtable with your table name.*/